# Unity - Vuforia coordinate systems and 3D model registration mechanism

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

This might be a broad question. If so redirect me to the right stack website.

I want to understand better the mechanism of how Unity and vuforia works. More specifically Marker(target)'s coordinate system, Unity's coordinate system, the Camera's coordinate system, and where the 3D model is registered. 
I have made this example : 
[image: marker-3D model].

- The marker's position is known inside Unity's coordinate system.
- The pen is a 3D model where its position and orientation is defined in Unity's coordinate system (dragged and dropped in the 3D environment). Let's say it's 20 units away from the marker on the Z-axis.

Now what I think happens when a camera is turned on is the following :
The camera detects where the marker is in its coordinate system (camera) and then unity registers the 3D model pen on the right position **knowing that it should be 20 units away from the Z-axis of the marker's coordinate system**.

If what I said is right then **my question** is :

> Where is the marker's coordinate system defined so that unity can say
>   it's 20 units away form the marker ? from what reference ? Since unity
>   initially knows only : position and orientation of the marker and the
>   3D model (pen) in the 3D virtual environment ?

Comment: Vuforia gets the distance from the camera by calculating it via the perspective and size of the recognized marker.

Comment: Yeah I understood this part, my problem is with, how is it decided in unity where to put the 3D model in the space relative to the marker (once you drag and drop the model close to the marker) ? Is there some kind of a coordinate system defined initially with the target inside unity? There must be some relationship initially defined between the marker and the model.. If so, where and how?

Comment: So my problem is with the distance from the 3D model to the marker not from the marker to the camera

Comment: Depends how you place it ... Usually you put the model as a child of the ImageTarget => Vuforia places the imageTarget in your Unity 3D world and you place your model related to that imageTarget.